# Why does static array return nil?

Tags: arrays, static, swift4

I have the following class with a static array:

```
class Test:NSObject{
    static let items = [1,2,3,4]
}
```

I access the array in `viewWillAppear` of the first view:

```
let someItem = Test.items.index(of:0)
```

and PO the items in the debug console since there is a breakpoint on the above line. I get the following:

> po Test.items ▿ 4 elements
>     - 0 : 1
>     - 1 : 2
>     - 2 : 3
>     - 3 : 4

However, `someItem` returns nil. Why does that happen? Shouldn't `1` be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items` does not have an element that equals 0.

[From Apple Developer Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689674-index)

> ## index(of:)
>
> Returns the first index where the specified value appears in the collection.

What you are looking for is **subscripting**:

```swift
let someItem = Test.items[0] //1
```